# Can't install .NET 3.5 after uninstalling .NET 4

Tags: .net, windows-7

We're using a hosted web app from an outside vendor. The app runs in IE 9 and the vendor says they prefer to use .NET 3.5. It *can* use .NET 4 if we run a registry fix.

After a Microsoft patch to IE last week we started having all kinds of problems and eventually couldn't even get into the app. We've worked with the vendor's support for 3 days with no luck. Yesterday, in desperation, they suggested we uninstall .NET 4 and reinstall 3.5. I ran the uninstall and rebooted, but the installer for 3.5 isn't doing anything. I double-click the installer, Windows asks if I want to run it, but nothing happens and Task Manager doesn't show any processes starting. I'm not getting any error messages.

Off the top of my head: could our malware app (Webroot Secure Anywhere) be blocking this? Or is it something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Window event log? there might be some messages there...

Have you check this out?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx

You can try that as your **last resort**, just check if 4.0 was completely removed and just if necessary remove 3.5 using this and try to re-install it.

Comment: Thanks. Followed that link and learned a lot. He had a link to .NET 3.5SP1. I downloaded that one and it at least responded to me, telling me to add/remove .NET via the Control Panel. The Control Panel said v3.5 was installed and Microsoft's verification tool confirmed it. I guess the 3.5 installer just doesn't do anything at all if it detects it already installed, while SP1 at least tells you to check Control Panel.